# many to one relations, get the results by attributes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use the entity with the realtions.

I have an entity page and another one articles. A page can have more than one article, but an article is just for one page.

My page entity

```
namespace theatreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * pages
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="theatreBundle\Entity\pagesRepository")
 */
class pages
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;
//getters and setters
```

My article entity:

```
<?php

namespace theatreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * article
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="theatreBundle\Entity\articleRepository")
 */
class article {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="theatreBundle\Entity\pages")
     */
    private $pages;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contenu", type="text")
     */
    private $contenu;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;
//getters and setters
```

I want now to have all the articles for 1 page. 
I have a variable $page, who contain the $nom attribute.

I create an

```
$articles = $this
                    ->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('theatreBundle:article')
                    ->findOneBy(array('nom'=> $page));
```

But nom doesn't exist. Anybody knows how to do that? I'm sur that this is very simple...

Best regards

EDIT:

This can work so:

```
    $id = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('theatreBundle:pages')
            ->findOneBy(array('nom'=> $page));
    $articles = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('theatreBundle:article')
            ->findOneBy(array('pages'=> $id));
```

But also, why have I created the many to one relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a simple one just define mapping for articles in your page entity

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
class pages
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="article", mappedBy="pages")
     */
    protected $articles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articles= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getArticles()
    {
       return $this->articles;
    }
}
```

Now you can get your page by nom the resultant object of page will have a collection of its related articles

```
$page= $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('theatreBundle:pages')
        ->findOneBy(array('nom'=> $page));

$page->getArticles(); /* All articles related to the queried page*/
```

[`Reference`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Comment: @anubis yes you need a bidirectional entity

Comment: I have to create always bidirectional entity? What's the difference?

Comment: @anubis it depends on you lets take your scenario if you need only articles and its corresponding page then you don't need to define a mapping in your pages entity but now you have a scenario to get all articles of your selected page then you need this mapping because its more handy than to have a querybuilder and i guess its better practice to have a bidirectional mapping as following official docs